# how to determine in applicationDidBecomeActive whether it is the initial iPhone app launch?

Tags: iphone, ios, background, uiapplicationdelegate

how to determine in how to determine in UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification whether it is the initial app launch?whether it is the initial app launch?

that is the initial start up of the application, as opposed to subsequent DidBecomeActive's due to the application being put in background and then to foreground (e.g. user goes to calendar then back to your app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:` put this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"alreadyLaunched"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Then, in `didBecomeActive`:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"alreadyLaunched"]) {
    // is NOT initial launch...
} else {
    // is initial launch...
}
```

Comment: ok thanks - no direct way - I could just create a specific instance variable in the appDelegate (a bool say) for this purpose too couldn't I then?

Comment: This doesn't constitute as an answer but the work here [iOS Post 4 application flow](http://www.cocoanetics.com/files/UIApplication_Delegate_post_4_v121.jpg]) helps understanding the accepted answer for this question

Comment: @FotisParaskevopoulos dead link sadly.  Is this it http://www.cocoanetics.com/files/UIApplication_Delegate_post_4_v121.jpg

Answer (score 27):

FWIW, the accepted answer tells you if the app has ever been launched before, not if the app is resuming from the background vs launching. Once the `alreadyLaunched` key has been set in preferences it will return `YES` when the app is launched in the future (vs resumed from background).

To detect if the app has resumed from the background you don't need to add anything to preferences. Rather, do the following in your app delegate implementation.

```
// myAppDelegate.m
//

@interface MyAppDelegate()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL activatedFromBackground;
@end

@implementation MyAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.activatedFromBackground = NO;

    // your code
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    self.activatedFromBackground = YES;

    // your code
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if (self.activatedFromBackground) {
        // whatever you want here
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to use the method mentioned by @XJones. Then I realized it has a potential issue: if "the initial app launch" means to check in applicationDidBecomeActive whether it was called the first time since the app was launched!  Because when app was relaunching the app (either through springboard, app switching or URL) all the above 3 delegate method will be called! So the safest way is to reset self.activatedFromBackground in applicationDidBecomeActive.