# How to check only when "Notification Center or Control Center" are triggered in applicationDidBecomeActive

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, notificationcenter, control-center

As we all know, applicationDidBecomeActive will call when we open and close the  Bottom Control Center / Top Noficication Center.

But I want to know in the applicationDidBecomeActive when **only because of these 2 events**, to handle some functionality when user opens and close Notification Center or Control Center.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

    if(/*Code for DidBecomeActive Called Because of Contol Center*/ --- )
    {

    }


if(/*Code for DidBecomeActive Called Because of Notification Center*/)
    {

    }


}
```

Any one help me to findout

**Code for DidBecomeActive Called Because of Notification Center**

**Code for DidBecomeActive Called Because of Contol Center**

Comment: Here you may find your [information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733730/how-to-determine-in-applicationdidbecomeactive-whether-it-is-the-initial-iphone).

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure you can achieve exactly what you want - but you can get close. When you pull the Notification Center down (or the Control Centre up, or enter App Switcher) you will get:

```
applicationWillResignActive
```

Closing the panel and returning to the app will call:

```
applicationDidBecomeActive
```

Now *fully backgrounding* the app instead calls this sequence:

```
applicationWillResignActive
applicationDidEnterBackground
```

And re-opening the app calls:

```
applicationWillEnterForeground
applicationDidBecomeActive
```

So all you need to do is use a flag to track the sequence:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL wasControlCenter;

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    _wasControlCenter = YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    _wasControlCenter = NO;
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    _wasControlCenter = NO;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    if (_wasControlCenter) {
        // Do your thing
    }    
}
```

Unfortunately I don't think there's a way to differentiate between Control Center, Notification Center, App Switcher etc.

Comment: Testing with iOS13 applicationWillResignActive is not being triggered when going to control panel, but applicationDidBecomeActive does when you come back.

Comment: Successfully validated by seeing the differences of the callbacks between app going to OS settings by opening `openSettingsURLString` vs. just pulling down the control center / notification center. Findings: when you have control center / notification center, you're not backgrounding the app, **you can still see the app in a blurry way**, you're just resigning it from being active. When control center is let go, app becomes active again. However for going to the settings app, the events are such: resignActive --> EnterBackground and then upon returning to app: EnterForeground --> BecomeActive