# When using AVFoundation, how to listen for Control Center Screen and Notification Center Screen activity

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I use AVFoundation for a video recording. When the app goes to the background I stop the capture session and when it enters the foreground I restart the capture session, everything works fine. I also use callKit to listen for incoming phone calls and that works fine too:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appWillEnterBackground), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
        
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appWillEnterForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)

@objc func appWillEnterBackground() {

    // if recording stop recording, stop timer, etc ...
    captureSession.stopRunning()
    previewLayer = nil
}

@objc func appWillEnterForeground() {

   if !captureSession.isRunning {
        captureSession.startRunning()
        initialize preview layer
   }
}
```

The problem is while the vc with the camera is active (recording or not) and when I swipe from the bottom to bring up the Control Center Screen or swipe from the top to bring down the Notification Center Screen `UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification` gets called and the capture session is stopped. When I remove either of those screens `UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification` doesn't get called and the capture session is no longer running.

What I want to do is when either of those screens surface I simply use a bool to prevent the capture session from stopping

```
var haveControlScreensSurfaced = false // toggle this true/false depending when the control screens enter and leave

 @objc func appWillEnterBackground() {

    if view.window != nil && haveControlScreensSurfaced { return }

    // if recording stop recording, stop timer, etc ...
    captureSession.stopRunning()
    previewLayer = nil
}
```

How can specifically listen for `Control Center Screen` and `Notification Center Screen` activity so that I can toggle my `haveControlScreensSurfaced` bool value to true/false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [way works good for an avplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42268286/4833705)

Since I needed a capture session long story short I used this. When sliding up/down either the Notification Center Screen or the Control Screen, `UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification` (app enters background) and `UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification` (app is about to enter foreground) **never get called**. I simply moved my code to there and problem solved:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didEnterBackground), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
        
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appWillEnterForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)

@objc func didEnterBackground() {

    // stop capture session
}

@objc func appWillEnterForeground() {

   // start capture session
}
```

Here is a breakdown of what happens when the notifications are triggered:

Pressing the Home Button, sending app to the background:

```
1- `UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification` gets called first
2- `UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification` gets called second // *** gets called when the HomeButton is pressed ***
```

Opening the app back up:

```
1- `UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification` gets called first  // *** gets called when the opening the app back up ***
2- `UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification` gets called second
```

Sliding down the Notification Center Screen from the top:

```
1- `UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification` gets called first
2- `UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification` gets called second
3- if using the `.AVCaptureSessionWasInterrupted` the `.videoDeviceNotAvailableInBackground` gets called third
4- `UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification` gets called fourth
```

Sliding the Notification Center Screen back up:

```
1- `UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification` gets called alone
2- if using the `.AVCaptureSessionInterruptionEnded` it gets called second
```

Sliding the Control Screen up from the bottom:

```
1- `UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification` gets called alone
```

Sliding the Control Screen back back down:

```
1- `UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification` gets called by alone
```